# Separate ground/neutral bars in sub

Tags: subpanel

OK..I have another sub-panel question.  My sub has a 50 amp gfci that powers (old) spa.  Currently this sub panel has a single neutral/ground bar.  This bar is bonded, (screw is in), to the metal enclosure.  There is an in-ground ground bar, of which a ground wire connects it to the neutral/ground bar.

There are three wires from the main, two hot and one neutral.  This is how the sub is configured and powered the (old) spa.  I have a new spa.  I know this configuration will work for the new spa.  I ask for your specific guidance on ensuring I end up with the correct/compliant configuration.

**If I need to run a ground wire from main to sub.  Can it be run separately outside of any conduit.

Comment: How is the existing feeder wiring run?

Comment: Please [edit](https://diy.stackexchange.com/posts/124398/edit) your existing question to add new details instead of asking a new question.